# Dual Boot/GRUB Question

Tags: grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 14 in dual boot with Windows 7 installed first. I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu and I was wondering if GRUB2 which comes with Ubuntu is likely to experience problems every time I update Windows 7?

I read previous posts stating that it is the case with Grub and Windows 8 but I wonder if it is the case with Windows 7 and Grub 2. I plan on never using Windows 8.

If so, how do you uninstall GRUB2 after you install EasyBCD to dual boot from Windows?

I also noticed that my Ubuntu partition still shows up as empty on Windows 7 disk manager --I used the Ubuntu CD automatic partition tool which used my empty partition. Is there anyway to rename an empty partition in the Windows 7 disk manager application?

Thank you for your time.

PS: I am still new to Linux and the StackExchange platform. I try to ensure my question is specific and follows your guidelines. I apologize in advance if it does not.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you not to use EasyBCD but to go with GRUB2.
GRUB2 will detect both Ubuntu and Windows 7 and will give you the option at boot time to select which operating system you want to start.

Do not mess with the Ubuntu partition from within Windows.
Windows is very intolerant with respect to other operating systems.
Furthermore if your Ubuntu partition contains an filesystem which is NOT FAT32 or NTFS (and this is most likely the case) then Windows will not recognize it anyway because Windows can't read the Linux type filesystems.

Linux can read FAT32 and NTFS (and ofcourse the typical Linux file systems) so always perform file system operations from within Linux.

Comment: You're welcome. B.T.W.: If you're happy with either of these answers you can accept one of them. Otherwise the question is still visible as 'open' on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the /boot/grub.cfg to timeout=0 it will make the grub page disappear faster.
I prefer to disable windows 7 updates they are too annoying.

the partition should appear as unknown partition on disk manager. I think you can't rename it.